# how to run code from sbt with a classpath?

Tags: sbt, slick

I'm trying to run the Slick code generation with a customized generator (my `ExampleCodeGenerator`). I place the `ExampleCodeGenerator.scala` into the `project` subdirectory, so that it's available to the build scripts. I construct a `classpath: Seq[File]` that contains the `classes` directory into which `ExampleCodeGenerator` is compiled, plus the JARs from `Compile / dependencyClasspath`.

If I follow [the lead given in the Slick documentation for sbt](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/code-generation.html#integrated-into-sbt) and write in my `.sbt` file:

```scala
runner.value.run("slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator",
  classpath, Seq(profile, driver, url, outputDir.getPath, pkg, "", "", "true", className, "true"), logger
)
```

I get a `ClassNotFoundException: scala.Serializable`.

If I try the [standalone instructions](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/code-generation.html#standalone-use) and write:

```scala
slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator.main(
  Array(profile, driver, url, outputDir.getPath, pkg, "", "", "true", className, "true")
)
```

I instead get `ClassNotFoundException: ExampleCodeGenerator`, even though the sbt code can find that class, and the called code is doing a `Class.forName()` in the same thread.

If I add the Scala library to the project's `libraryDependencies` and retry the first approach, I still get the `Serializable` error.

---

I've seen [Chris Vogt's really old example](https://github.com/slick/slick-codegen-customization-example). But I don't think that it should be necessary to split the project into two projects in order to do this.

My code is at https://github.com/performantdata/custom-slickgen.

Comment: It's interesting that if I add `Class.forName(className)` into the `build.sbt` directly before the `SourceCodeGenerator.main`, it doesn't throw.

Comment: It seems that I'm running into a variant of [this](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Running-Project-Code.html#Deserialization+and+class+loading).

Comment: The difference that I notice in the debugger is that a `Class.forName` directly inside the task definition has an extra `URLClassLoader` at the top of its stack that contains the `project/target/scala-2.12/sbt-1.0/classes` URL, while the `Class.forName` inside `SourceCodeGenerator.main` doesn't have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have this figured out.

The problem in the first case is that, in order to have my `ExampleCodeGenerator` available in the main build scripts, I place it in the `project` subdirectory. These files, though, are compiled with a version of the Scala compiler that sbt uses—in this case 2.12.14. In 2.12, `scala.Serializable` is present, but in 2.13 it was replaced with a type alias. So this, in general, won't work, because I'm `run`-ing the code with the Scala version of the base project, which can be different, and is in fact 2.13. I'm able to force this 2.12 `classes` directory into the classpath, but to no avail.

In the second case, my guess is that the `Class.forName()` being called from `SourceCodeGenerator.main` is using the class loader of the `SourceCodeGenerator` object's class, and that loader is an instance of `sbt.internal.PluginManagement.PluginClassLoader`, a `java.net.URLClassLoader` subclass that contains all the URLs of the JARs in the (base or build, not sure) project, but *not* the build project's `classes` directory URL. So that loader can't find `ExampleCodeGenerator`.

The solution seems to be what I have usually seen: create another subproject that builds a JAR that the base project depends on. This seems unavoidable.

Comment: The only other alternative that I've come up with is to have a task in the base project that compiles `ExampleCodeGenerator` prior to the compilation of managed sources.

Comment: This would need to be done with [a custom dependency configuration](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Custom-Dependency-Configuration.html), which is probably more confusing for others to understand, and more fragile.